# How to setup tang/clevis failover on headless debian?

Tags: boot, initramfs, disk-encryption

### Goal:

I want to run a debian host with NBDE/FDE:

1. For decryption it should **check for a tang server first**.
2. If not available it should **fallback to manual decryption via SSH** (busybox or the like).

### Problem:

**How do I setup initramfs to start a ssh-server (for manual unlock) if clevis fails?**

Sidenote: In general, I think need some more background on the Luks-initramfs bootup mechanics. **Please be verbose..**

### Context:

- **Clevis/tang decrypt:** I used the [**instructions**](https://github.com/hetzneronline/community-content/blob/master/tutorials/install-ubuntu-2004-with-full-disk-encryption-with-clevis-and-tang/01.en.md) provided by my hoster to setup clevis/tang on a headless *ubuntu* server. However, I need *debian* (to run Proxmox), so I modified ([add dns to initramfs](https://github.com/latchset/clevis/issues/148#issuecomment-882103016)) the post-install script (`post-install.sh`) a bit.
- **Failover: manual decrypt:** There's also a [**script**](https://github.com/hetzneronline/community-content/blob/master/tutorials/install-ubuntu-2004-with-full-disk-encryption/01.en.md) to setup an LUKS-FDE for ubuntu: This works fine with the debian.
- Dedicated server, full root access, hoster: Hetzner
- There's a rescue system (network booted) that is used to start the provisioning and that can access the non-encrypted drives.
- I am still in a testing phase. **There's no need take any existing data into account.**

---

### Edit:

I solved the problem by simply merging the to `post-install.sh` scripts. Potentially critical is the sequence of installed apt packages, i.e. `dropbear-initramfs` before clevis.

I leave the question open, as I would like to understand the solution more in depth. **Why does this work?**